# Identity server 4 - deactivate the discovery endpoint

Tags: c#, mongodb, openid, identityserver4

I am developing an Authentication server to deliver tokens to be used to consume our API using **IdentityServer4**.
I am using MongoDB as database on which I have the users allowed to get tokens, and to be more secure I am using a custom certificate to encrypt the token.
This is how my **Startup.cs** of my `AuthenticationServer` looks like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "cert", "whatever.pfx"), "whatever");

    services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(cert)
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Config.GetApiResources());

    services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

    services.AddTransient<IClientStore, ClientStore>();
    services.AddTransient<IProfileService, UserProfileService>();
    services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, UserResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
    services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<User.Model.User>, PasswordHasher<User.Model.User>>();

}
```

As you can see I have custom implementation of those interfaces that do the client authentication and password validation. This is working fine.

Then I am protecting *another application* with the tokens generated, and I have there defined that it has to use the `IdentityServerAuthetication` (localhost:5020 is where my `AuthenticationServer` is running)

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5020",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ApiName = "MyAPI",
            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

All works fine, but if I shutdown the `AuthenticationServer` then I get this error from the API I am protecting:

> System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:5020/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
>      at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.d__1.MoveNext()
>   fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]

So what it seems is the API is going to the *discovery endpoint* to see where is the endpoint to decrypt the token (I guess it would be `userinfo_endpoint`).

My point is:

- It seems that the discovery endpoint is used to get information of how to use the authentication server (for me makes sense for open APIs), but in our case we are not developing and open API, so our clients would be just the ones we have agreement and we will tell them in advance the endpoints and we will most likely restrict by IP address.
- Is there any way to deactivate the discovery endpoint and to setup on the API the certificate to properly decrypt the token.

Maybe I am missing the complete picture and I am saying silly things, but I would be glad to understand the concepts behind.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have the discovery endpoint off/unavailable and still validate tokens.

You'll need to implement IConfigurationManager and pass that to a JwtBearerOptions object inside of IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions.

Here's some example code:

```
public class OidcConfigurationManager : IConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>
{
    public OidcConfigurationManager()
    {
        SetConfiguration();
    }
    private OpenIdConnectConfiguration _config;
    public Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(_config);
    }
    public void RequestRefresh()
    {
    }

    private void SetConfiguration()
    {
        // Build config from JSON
        var configJson =
            @"{""issuer"":""http://localhost/id"",""jwks_uri"":""http://localhost/id/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks"",""authorization_endpoint"":""http://localhost/id/connect/authorize"",""token_endpoint"":""http://localhost/id/connect/token"",""userinfo_endpoint"":""http://localhost/id/connect/userinfo"",""end_session_endpoint"":""http://localhost/id/connect/endsession"",""check_session_iframe"":""http://localhost/id/connect/checksession"",""revocation_endpoint"":""http://localhost/id/connect/revocation"",""introspection_endpoint"":""http://localhost/id/connect/introspect"",""frontchannel_logout_supported"":true,""frontchannel_logout_session_supported"":true,""scopes_supported"":[""openid"",""profile"",""api1"",""offline_access""],""claims_supported"":[""sub"",""name"",""family_name"",""given_name"",""middle_name"",""nickname"",""preferred_username"",""profile"",""picture"",""website"",""gender"",""birthdate"",""zoneinfo"",""locale"",""updated_at""],""grant_types_supported"":[""authorization_code"",""client_credentials"",""refresh_token"",""implicit"",""password""],""response_types_supported"":[""code"",""token"",""id_token"",""id_token token"",""code id_token"",""code token"",""code id_token token""],""response_modes_supported"":[""form_post"",""query"",""fragment""],""token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported"":[""client_secret_basic"",""client_secret_post""],""subject_types_supported"":[""public""],""id_token_signing_alg_values_supported"":[""RS256""],""code_challenge_methods_supported"":[""plain"",""S256""]}";
        _config = new OpenIdConnectConfiguration(configJson);

        // Add signing keys if not present in json above
        _config.SigningKeys.Add(new X509SecurityKey(cert));
    }
}
```

Now pass that config object to some JwtBearerOptions inside of your IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions (a bit annoying, but it's the only way I know of)

```
var identityServerOptions = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5020",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ApiName = "MyAPI",
    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,

};
var jwtBearerOptions = new JwtBearerOptions() {ConfigurationManager = new OidcConfigurationManager()};
var combinedOptions = CombinedAuthenticationOptions.FromIdentityServerAuthenticationOptions(identityServerOptions);
combinedOptions.JwtBearerOptions = jwtBearerOptions;
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(combinedOptions);
```

Now your API will be able to receive tokens and validate the signatures even if the OIDC discovery endpoint is off.

Answer (score 1):

The API validation middleware downloads a copy of the discovery document at startup - and then (at least by default) - every 24h.

It might re-trigger download if signature validation fails (to accommodate for out of schedule key rollovers).

You can define all configuration values statically - but you are losing all the benefits of dynamic configuration updates.

If your discovery endpoint is not available, then probably the whole token service is not functional which is probably a bigger problem.

Comment: Would this mean that having the discovery endpoint available will not pose security risks? .. I am coming from WCF where I had to disable the metadata for endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The IdentityServer needs the public key of your X509 certificate to validate the `access_token`. It is using the discovery endpoint to get that public key, and is refreshing the saved public key every now and then (because the public key could change).

If the IdentityServer is not accessible, your API can't guarantee that the `access_token` is valid. You can increase the caching of the results of the `access_token` validation requests.

I'm not entirely sure with IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation, but with IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation, you can set the `ValidationMode` to `Local` only, so it just downloads the public key once.